# JBoss AS 7.3 vs 7.4 and differences

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I can find the EAP component differences, but where can I find differences between JBoss AS 7.3 and 7.4? I am trying to decide between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences are the same as for EAP, this is because **EAP 6.3.0 GA built from AS 7.4** and  **EAP 6.2.0 GA built from AS 7.3**. The EAP code repository was forked/rebased from AS7 after `7.2.0 tag`.

And as such has its own lifecycle and has diverted considerably from AS7/WildFly (upstream) repository.

In short there is no such thing as JBoss 7.3 or 7.4 as it is internal version.

Code for all EAP releases is available on ftp and you can always build it yourself and use without restrictions (ftp://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/jbeap/).

You can see component details in https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673

I hope this help.